# Finding the m-th coefficient of an equation

Tags: number-theory

Does anyone know how to find the m-th coefficient of

$-t=(3+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!})(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n \frac{t^n}{n!})$?

The answer is:

$0=3 \frac{D_m}{m!}+2\sum_{k=1}^{m/2} \frac{1}{(2k)!} D_{m-2k} \frac{1}{(m-2k)!}$

but i don't understand it why this is the m-th coefficient.

This is an exercise trying to find a recursive formula for $D_m$. In this exercise the numbers $D_m$ are defined by the generating function:

$G(t)=\frac{-t}{e^t +1 + e^{-t}} = \sum_{m\geq 0 } D_m \frac{t^m}{m!}$

Comment: is this not the cauchy product?

Comment: @abel I have no idea. This is an exercise trying to find a recursive formula for $D_m$ where $G(t)=\frac{-t}{e^t +1 + e^{-t}}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} D_m \frac{t^m}{m!}$.